# R subsetting vector to replace NAs

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and I have come across a code which it is used to replace NAs with latest non-NAs values which I don't fully understand, please, anybody can explain it to me?:

This is the code:

```
z  <- !is.na(a)                  
z  <- z | !cumsum(z)             
y  <- a[z][cumsum(z)]
```

I have a vector "a" which contains numbers and NAs:

```
a<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,3,4,5,NA,5,5,5,NA,NA,NA)
```

by running the first line I get "z"
 which are boolean values of the "a" vector:

```
> z
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

so now I know that if I want to access to the first element of the vector I can just use the symbol "[" to subset the number 1 :

```
> a[1]
[1] 1
```

similarly, if I want the first 3 elements:

```
> a[1:3]
[1]  1 NA NA
```

Why by typing the following is subsetting the TRUE values? 
Is it not supposed to return again the entire vector including NAs? because z is a vector of all boolean values...

```
> a[z]
[1] 1 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

To subset FALSE apparently is

```
> a[!z]
    [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Finally, I can understand the cumulative function "cumsum":

```
> cumsum(z)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 7
```

but I don't understand why by typing :

```
> a[z][cumsum(z)]
```

it returns:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

What does "[ ][ ]" means?
I know that for instance 
by typing

```
> a[z][1]
```

I can access to the first element of the subsetted TRUE boolean values

```
[1] 1
```

but I don't get the third line of code.

Comment: Input is a<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,3,4,5,NA,5,5,5,NA,NA,NA)

Comment: Output is [1] 1 1 1 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

Comment: the code I found is correct, just that I am not understanding it

Comment: Note that the zoo package has functions `na.locf` and `na.locf0` (last occurrence carried forward) to do this.  Also there are many other na.* functions there too for different types of NA substitution. Note that if the values in `a` are non-decreasing as is the case in the example in the question then `cummax(ifelse(is.na(a), 0, a))` would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here 'z' is a logical `vector` i.e. having TRUE/FALSE values.  When we do `cumsum` (cumulative sum), at each value of 'TRUE', it gets added 1

```
cumsum(z)
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 7
```

Now, let's look at

```
a[z]
#[1] 1 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

Here, the values of 'a' got subset by the corresponding elements of TRUE values in 'z'

When we use the `cumsum(z)` as an index, it is saying that first 4 elements should be the value at position 1 from `a[z]`, 5th element should be from position 2 of `a[z]`, 6th from position 3 of `a[z]` and so on...  In short, the values in `a[z]` are replicated based on the index from `cumsum(z)`

```
a[z][cumsum(z)]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

which is the same as `rep`

```
rep(a[z], c(4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

or

```
rep(a[z], tabulate(cumsum(z)))
```

---

To understand how this works, it may be better to use some `print` statements in a `for` loop

```
for(i in cumsum(z)) {
   cat("cumulative sum vector", paste(cumsum(z), collapse=","), sep="\n")
  cat(paste0("cumulative sum of z index i: ", i), sep="\n")
  cat("value of a[z] vector:", paste(a[z], collapse=","), sep= "\n")
  cat("value of a[z] from indexing", a[z][i], sep="\n") 
  cat("----------------")
 }
```

Comment: great explanation, so basically the function "cumsum" is used as index, interesting